# PDFBox Android Failing Sample Code

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I'd like to use PDFBox for Android in order to create a PDF from scratch. 
An image and a table should be displayed, as well as a repeating PDF-Header for each page.

The version I'm using is com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.0, which can be found at https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android.

So I cloned the repository and tried to run the sample code. 
Edit1: Here's the link to the sample code: 
https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/tom_roush/pdfbox/sample/MainActivity.java

I've been able to install it on my testdevice, but the pdfcreation fails cause of a FileNotFoundException: Path (Access Denied).

So I tried to change the path, where to save the PDF to various different locations, but it's not working for me. Any advice on how to save the pdf in order to open it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add, request and grant `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: thanks a lot. Thought that I've done that already by granting write permission in the manifest. But little did I know, that in "newer" android versions you've to request for access specificly.